# Can I use a participle like this?

Tags: participles

Is it appropriate to use a participle as I did it in the sentence below?

- We often come across some resources **published** using a foreign language.

I suppose that if we used **"which (or that) are"**, it would be grammatically correct.

- We often come across some resources **which (that) are published** using a foreign language.

Comment: Yet, I believe that the second option sounds weird and a bit wordy.

Comment: *We often find resources published in foreign languages* is much shorter and imho much more "natural".

Comment: I agree. Is it grammatically correct? If so, then thank you a lot - you've answered my question.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking about here. If you're just wondering whether it's "grammatically correct" to ***not*** include ***which / that are*** before the main verb *(**published**)*, the answer is Yes - it's entirely optional. See earlier question [Is 'that' optional after linking verb?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122064/is-that-optional-after-linking-verb)

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted to know.

Comment: I cannot say it does. There was a question about omitting "that", but I was wondering only about a participle - I was not sure whether I can treat them as I did in those sentences. Now I know, thank you and yxtao who has also answered my question.

Comment: I do not think the linked question, which does not involve a gerund form, is sufficiently similar to close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Both sentences have the same meaning.
2. The structure of them are different.The first sentence has a participle to modify the noun; the second sentence has relative clause.
3. The first one is more concise than the second one.

A participle is a form of a verb that is used in a sentence to modify a noun, noun phrase, verb, or verb phrase, and then plays a role similar to an adjective or adverb. It is one of the types of nonfinite verb forms.
source: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/styleguide/chapter/participles/

A relative pronoun is a pronoun that introduces a relative clause. It is called a "relative" pronoun because it "relates" to the word that its relative clause modifies. source: https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-relative.htm